# Android WebSocket - disconnection detection strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, java, android, websocket, chat

This is my first question here in StackOverflow after years that i use it :D

I'm working on an application that use [ToolTallNate API](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket). I just find a small issue while trying to detect a disconnection due to a line problem (like low signal; in my situation I simulate the line problem deactivating my local network ).

After digging in documentation, I found basically two different situations:

**1) Manually Close**

When I close the websocket on my own (so not due to a line problem) the application flow is basically this

1. Call the `close()` method that is defined on WebSocketClient.java
2. This method call the `close()` method of WebSocketImpl.java

   ```
   @Override
   public void close( int code, String message ) {
       engine.close( code, message );
   }
   ```
3. In the method `close( int code, String message, boolean remote ) {*code*}`, The `ABNORMAL` and `NORMAL` close cases are divided but it seems like the important part are more or less the same

   ```
   readystate is setted to  **READYSTATE.CLOSING**

   readystate = READYSTATE.CLOSING;
   ```
4. In the WebSocketClient class there is a running thread ( that start on websocket connection ) where there is a while loop that check the **readystate** value

   ```
   try {
       while ( !isClosing() 
           && !isClosed() 
           && ( readBytes = istream.read( rawbuffer ) ) != -1 ) {
           engine.decode( ByteBuffer.wrap( rawbuffer, 0, readBytes ) );
   }
   engine.eot();
   ```
5. When readystate is setted to CLOSING condition the application call the `eot();` method where the connection is close and through the **closeConnection()** method the  **onWebsocketClose()** method is called and the all the thread are interrupted and , most important , the `stopConnectionLostTimer()` is called ; this timer is used to check connection state using the classic ping/pong method

So this seem to work perfectly

**LINE NETWORK PROBLEM DISCONNECTION**

To test this situation I deactivate my local network (where I'm testing my application ) to simulate a problem on line.

The program flow is basically the same but in this situation the close method is called in the **startConnectionLostTimer()** where if there is a delay on server response it call the close() method with the ABNORMAL_CLOSE condition

Also with this condition the close method set the **readystate = READYSTATE.CLOSING;** but now it seems like the thread where there is the while loop checking for state is waiting and the eot  method ( that close the connection and stop the connection lost timer ) is never called and the timer never stopped.

I also tried to override the onClosing() method and call the stopConnectionLostTimer() method but again nothing happen because something seems to be stuck...

Another Strange beehaviour ( or probably just form me )  is that  when i reactivate my local network it finally goes through the eot method to close and stop everything...

So I was expecting that after the connection lost timeout everything has to work like a normal manually close()...

where I'm wrong ?? ( because i know that there is an error on my argument :D )

**EDIT:**
Hello, i found another important thing that is the reason why the while statement is blocked for a long time before he can close the connection;
In the while statement there is a condition

```
( readBytes = istream.read( rawbuffer ) )
```

and this function after something like 2 minutes catch an exception "no route no host" .
I suppose that after a sort of timeout ( but i can't find it ) it call the exception and so finally the connection is closed

Comment: Rather than quoting documentation, could you expose your code and highlight which part of your code creates the problem? The only thing I understood is "How to handle disconnection problem"...

Comment: Hi, the problem is that 99% of the code i'm studing now is not made by me; i'm basically testing the disconnection detention of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a way to manage that timeout ; 
In the standard implementation i can't set the timeout for the input stream read method so i simply create my own WebSocketClient class and when the socket is created , i also set the timemout with setSoTimeout

```
socket = new Socket( proxy );
socket.setSoTimeout(20000);   //for 20 second of timeout ; it's in millisecond
```